# Why my computer keep crashing? [With some data]

Tags: windows-7, memory, crash

Just bought this PC used from a guy, it has the following config:

- AMD FX-8120
- HD 7850 2GB Core Edition
- (4x) OCZ Gold Edition 2GB DDR3 1066Mhz
- Asus M5A78L LE

This PC should run games like GTA IV and Skyrim without lag, according to benchmarks. But it lags. It's playable, but there's a LOT of FPS drops everytime. Temperatures are low. This is my first issue. The second is the random crashes.

Ran MemTest for 10 hours, results:

[image]

THE BSOD that pops up from time to time:

- MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (most frequent)
- IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL (1x - I have installed only AMD Catalyst, Windows is brand new)

I want to add logs and more data here, what could be useful?

Edit

What **Whocrashed** has to say:

> computer name: LUCAS-PC windows version: Windows 7 Service Pack 1,
>   6.1, build: 7601 windows dir: C:\Windows Hardware: ASUSTeK Computer INC., M5A78L LE CPU: AuthenticAMD AMD FX(tm)-8120 Eight-Core Processor
>   AMD586, level: 21 8 logical processors, active mask: 255 RAM:
>   8571183104 total VM: 2147352576, free: 1957081088
>
> **Crash Dump Analysis**
>
> Crash dump directory: C:\Windows\Minidump
>
> Crash dumps are enabled on your computer.
>
> On Thu 10/04/2014 13:31:59 GMT your computer crashed crash dump file:
>   C:\Windows\memory.dmp
>
> This was probably caused by the following module: Unknown (0x00000000)
>   Bugcheck code: 0xA (0xFFFFF68000002F20, 0x0, 0x0, 0xFFFFF80002CCA16A)
>   Error: IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
>
> Bug check description: This indicates that Microsoft Windows or a
>   kernel-mode driver accessed paged memory at DISPATCH_LEVEL or above.
>
> This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to
>   be caused by a hardware problem.  A third party driver was identified
>   as the probable root cause of this system error.  Google query:
>   IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
>
> On Thu 10/04/2014 02:39:41 GMT your computer crashed crash dump file:
>   C:\Windows\Minidump\040914-15381-01.dmp This was probably caused by
>   the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x4B2AEC)  Bugcheck code: 0x124
>   (0x0, 0xFFFFFA80079788F8, 0x0, 0x0) Error: WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR
>
> file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe product: Microsoft®
>   Windows® Operating System company: Microsoft Corporation description:
>   NT Kernel & System Bug check description: This bug check indicates
>   that a fatal hardware error has occurred. This bug check uses the
>   error data that is provided by the Windows Hardware Error Architecture
>   (WHEA).  This is likely to be caused by a hardware problem problem.
>   This problem might be caused by a thermal issue.  The crash took place
>   in the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is caused by another
>   driver that cannot be identified at this time.

Here are the requested pictures of CPU-Z:

[image]

Comment: what does the analyze tab of whocrashed say?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PQQsxqhG

Comment: Just crashed again, by MEMORY_MANAGEMENT http://pastebin.com/TXKRt6GD

Comment: post some pictures of CPU-Z (Memory and SPD tab)

Comment: Made a more complete post at this forum, please take a look http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2100803/wtf-wrong-computer-long-post-data.html

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here it is: http://i.imgur.com/GYMivvV.png

Comment: have you modified the North bridge frequency? For my old Athlon X4 it is only 2000MHz.

Comment: What power supply do you have? Wondering if an underpowered power supply is causing instability

Comment: Cooler Master Extreme Power Plus 600W (http://www.coolermaster.com/powersupply/extreme/extreme-power-plus-600w/) I don't trust this PSU though, I dislike it

Comment: @magicandre1981 not that I know